# NOT LIKE operator doesn't work when I use OR (sqlite db)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table like this:

```
ID | Junk Food(TEXT) 
---|---------------
 1 |  Potato chips
   |  Candy bar
---|---------------
   |  Pizza
 2 |  Potato chips
   |  Ice cream  
---|---------------
 3 |  Hot dog
   |  Doughnut
```

I want to select Junk Food column where it has "Potato chips" value but it doesn't have "Ice cream" value and the following query works correct.

```
"SELECT Junk Food FROM table WHERE Junk Food LIKE '%Potato chips%' AND Junk Food NOT LIKE '%Ice cream%';"
```

But when I add an "OR" condition like below, it doesn't care about NOT LIKE anymore and brings Ice cream anyway.

```
"SELECT Junk Food FROM table WHERE Junk Food LIKE '%Potato chips%' OR Junk Food LIKE '%Hot dog%' AND Junk Food NOT LIKE '%Ice cream%';"
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT Junk Food FROM table WHERE 
 (Junk Food LIKE '%Potato chips%' OR Junk Food LIKE '%Hot dog%') 
 AND Junk Food NOT LIKE '%Ice cream%';"
```

try this, or condition is must be with () so its consider only one part.